# Google TV - Javascript Remote Keycodes

Tags: google-tv

Anyone have a reference to the keycodes for sony remote, I have play and stop working but need pause keycode, play pause seems to be referencing the same keycode but the buttons are seperate on the remote

Answer (score 1):

Here are the media keycodes:
https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_controlguide#MediaKeys

Comment: The URL fragment #MediaKeys does not exist on that page

Answer (score 0):

The controls are mapped to similar Android keys. The corresponding key codes can be found here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent

Please also note [Google TV guidelines for building TV navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/navigation).

If you need to know which keycode a specific key on your remote has I can recommend using [KeyMapper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.sds100.keymapper&hl=de&gl=US) which is free, available for Google TV and allows you to remap almost any hardware key to another function. It also shows you what keycode is triggered by a key.